# Looking for an html Slider (HTMl, JQuery, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

Im looking for an html slider that will look like this :
[image]

that give me the ability to assign the range , and if the range is larger than the slider size ,i should have these arrows to go to the right and left.

Im sure there is someone has done that.

Comment: Have you thought about making this on your own? It should only take a few minutes. Probably keywords to search are "jquery pagination" in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a plugin that does what you want. Download it [here](http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/). Its called jPaginate

Answer (score 0):

http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/stable/demo/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.